# Loaded from another DataContext?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, datacontext

In my previous applications when I used linq-to-sql I would always use one class to put my linq-to-sql code in, so I would only have one `DataContext`.

My current application though is getting too big and I started splitting my code up in different classes (One for Customer, one for Location, one for Supplier...) and they all have their own DataContext `DatabaseDesignDataContext dc = new DatabaseDesignDataContext();`

Now when I try to save a contact with a location (which I got from a different DataContext) I get the following error:

> "An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext.  This is not supported."

I assume this is because I create a `DataContext` for every class, but I wouldn't know how to this differently?

I'm looking for any ideas, thanks.

My classes look like the following:

```
 public class LocatieManagement
{
    private static DatabaseDesignDataContext dc = new DatabaseDesignDataContext();

    public static void addLocatie(locatie nieuweLocatie)
    {
        dc.locaties.InsertOnSubmit(nieuweLocatie);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<locatie> getLocaties()
    {
        var query = (from l in dc.locaties
                     select l);
        IEnumerable<locatie> locaties = query;

        return locaties;
    }

    public static locatie getLocatie(int locatie_id)
    {
        var query = (from l in dc.locaties
                     where l.locatie_id == locatie_id
                     select l).Single();

        locatie locatie = query;
        return locatie;

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Another solution I found for this is to create one parent class `DataContext`

```
public class DataContext
{
    public static DatabaseDesignDataContext dc = new DatabaseDesignDataContext();
}
```

And let all my other classes inherit this one.

```
 public class LocatieManagement : DataContext
 {
        public static void addLocatie(locatie nieuweLocatie)
        {
            dc.locaties.InsertOnSubmit(nieuweLocatie);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
 }
```

Then all the classes use the same DataContext.

Comment: This is a bad idea if you want do any transactional processing (which you should be doing). Also if are using multiple threads or if it is a web app, you will run into problems when more than one thread is trying to use the same data context. This also prevents more than one simultaneous database connection from being used so everything is relying on the same connection.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know what transactional processing is though. How would you solve this problem?

Comment: What I mean is that you should create a new DataContext and use it while performing some piece of work. And then get rid of it (do your work in a `using (MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext())` block). Don't use a global data context - a new one for each "thing" you need to do. For instance, if you are loading data for a web page, use a single data context for that page view. If you are doing a multi-step operation in which all steps are related and rely on each other, use a single data context for that entire process as well. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

That happens if the entity is still attached to the original datacontext. Turn off deferred loading (dc.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false):

```
partial class SomeDataContext
{
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
        this.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

You may also need to serialize/deserialize it once (e.g. using datacontractserializer) to disconnect it from the original DC, here's a clone method that use the datacontractserializer:

```
internal static T CloneEntity<T>(T originalEntity) where T : someentitybaseclass
{
    Type entityType = typeof(T);

    DataContractSerializer ser =
        new DataContractSerializer(entityType);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ser.WriteObject(ms, originalEntity);
        ms.Position = 0;
        return (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to turn off Deffered loading in every class? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't use deferred loading / lazy loading, you can turn it off in a single place by adding it to the datacontext's OnCreated...  (I'll update my answer with an example of this)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're trying to manage data from differing contexts - you will need to properly detach and attach your objects to proceed - however, I would suggest preventing the need to do this.

So, first things first: *remove the data context instances from your entity classes*.

From here create 'operational' classes that expose the CRUDs and whatnot to work with that specific type of entity class, which each function using a dedicated data context for that *unit of work*, perhaps overloading to accept a current context for when a unit of work entails subsequent operations.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean with operational classes. I updated my first post with an example of one class. 
Do you mean that I should use something like inheritance? 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry for the terminology confusion, but the practice is just as Justin suggestions: using a repo pattern, where the repos accept and return types of entities, going off to the db to get them (or from the cache if your repo implements such things) and set them in one fell swoop, finally closing the data context.

Comment: I see, sadly enough I don't really know how to do this. I have never used interfaces or repo pattern before. (I'm still learning)
I'll try looking into it, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know everybody probably gets tired of hearing this, but you really should look at using Repositories for Data Access (and using the Unit of Work pattern to ensure that all of the repositories that are sharing a unit of work are using the same DataContext).

You can read up on how to do things here: [Revisiting the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns with Entity Framework](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/06/21/revisiting-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework.aspx) (the same concepts apply to LINQ to SQL as well).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not very familiar with Interfaces / Repositories, I'll try reading the link you provided.

Comment: This answer is "go read something else" -- a glorified link only answer.  It doesn't provide any helpful information directly.